# MYSQL: Join, Count & Rank based on 2nd table

Tags: php, mysql, join, count, window-functions

I have two tables I'm working with in MySQL v5.5.33: members & member_points

Structured as follows:

**members**:

```
  id  Name
  1   John    
  2   Jane
```

**member_points**:

```
  id  id_from  id_to
  1      1       2
  2      2       1
  3      2       1
```

I was able to get this far, but unable to finish the last 3 columns and rank/sort properly

```
 id  name  total_sent  total_received  sent_minus_received  rank
 1   John      1                                
 2   Jane      2
```

This is my current code, which I was able to achieve the above.

```
SELECT *
     , a.id
     , COUNT(m.id) AS id_from_count
  FROM members AS a
  LEFT 
  JOIN member_points AS m 
    ON a.id = m.id_from
 GROUP 
    BY a.id
```

However the result I'm looking to achieve, includes total received, the variance or difference between sent and received, and lastly ranked based on the difference.

```
 id  name  total_sent  total_received  sent_minus_received  rank
 2   Jane      2            1                 1               1
 1   John      1            2                -1               2
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Currently using Version 5

Comment: My apologies. localhost currently on 5.5.33

Comment: Well. Additionally - describe carefully ranking algo.

Comment: 1st sorted by sent_minus_received... the higher the number the higher the rank, the lower/negative the number the lower the rank... if the sent_minus_received number tied with others, then the id should determine the sort order. ascending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT m.id, 
       m.name,
       SUM(m.id = mp.id_from) total_sent,
       SUM(m.id = mp.id_to) total_received,
       SUM(m.id = mp.id_from) - SUM(m.id = mp.id_to) `var(sent-received)`,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY {unclear from question text} ) `rank`
FROM members m
CROSS JOIN member_points mp
GROUP BY m.id, 
         m.name
```

> Currently using Version 5 ... My apologies. localhost currently on 5.5.33

```
SELECT subquery.*, 
       @rank := @rank + 1 `rank`
FROM (SELECT m.id, 
             m.name,
             SUM(m.id = mp.id_from) total_sent,
             SUM(m.id = mp.id_to) total_received,
             SUM(m.id = mp.id_from) - SUM(m.id = mp.id_to) `var(sent-received)`
      FROM members m
      CROSS JOIN member_points mp
      GROUP BY m.id, 
               m.name) subquery, 
     (SELECT @rank := 0) variable
ORDER BY `var(sent-received)` DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=29180f26e68480903810f1795681c5f0)

Comment: if there is a member with 0 stats (to & from), they don't show? How would i be able to include all members with zeros?

Comment: @Andrew If two or more members have the same balance value then they will obtain different ranks, and their ranking order is unpredictable. If you need some definite ordering add proper expression to the end of outer ORDER BY expression. If you need these rows to have the same (equal) rank then add one more variable for to store the rank of prevoius row.

Comment: @Andrew *if there is a member with 0 stats (to & from), they don't show?* Why? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=31af1c77c7205a3f814e94b9f7cbd60d

Comment: Got it. this makes since... as long as there is one transaction tied to a member, then all members will be included.. if there are absolutely no transactions (clean db) then that's where no members will show.... Your solution is perfect. thanks so much for your assistance Akina.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can join, aggregate, and rank with window functions:

```
select
    m.id,
    m.name,
    sum(m.id = mp.id_from) total_sent,
    sum(m.id = mp.id_to) total_recieved,
    sum(m.id = mp.id_from) - sum(m.id = mp.id_to) diff,
    rank() over(order by sum(m.id = mp.id_from) - sum(m.id = mp.id_to)) rnk
from members as m
left join member_points mp as mp on m.id in (mp.id_from, mp.id_to)
group by m.id, m.name
order by diff desc
```

Comment: LEFT jon makes no sense - INNER is enough.

Comment: @Akina: that's in case there are members without any point.

Comment: Points sent to nobody or received from nowhere? mmm... maybe.